# What recognizes RAM (CPU, board, or..)?

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu, motherboard

Sir.
--I was wondering what components are responsible for recognizing RAM in a laptop.  I might upgrade my CPU if I then can extend RAM beyond the current limit.  VirtualizationTech needed for some rendering(I thought anyway).
--I have installed an single core (35Watt) 45nm CPU and want to put in a:
quad core (45Watt) 45nm CPU.  Same Sockets, temp and year.  Just an extra 10 Watts - is that bad?

--If I upgrade the CPU can I install faster ram?

--Re: If the CPU is soldered - Not every pin is soldered?!  How do I find out if my laptop board supports what CPU upgrade?  I like this laptop.

I also think I heard of a program a long time ago that made the computer recognize HDD/SSD/orUSB-SD as RAM.  thanks for the Virtual Memory info : ) Is Vmem automatic?  My programs shut down sometimes and computer is slow.

Comment: you have completely mixed up a weird confused heoretical question, with the practical question of thinking of upgrading your laptop

Comment: There is a max RAM that is based on the motherboard. So if you look at the tech spec of the motherboard then it says how much max RAM. Also a website like crucial.com would say for a laptop

Comment: Hard drive can work as RAM that's called virtual memory and doesn't use any software and that is not fast. Alternatively, RAM can work as a hard disk, that's called a RAM Disk and I don't think people use them anymore and you'd only get a small amount of space to use like a fast disk drive.

Comment: Have you checked if you even can upgrade the CPU?  In most laptops this is not possible as the CPU is soldered directly to the main board.  The main board would also have to support the new CPU (same socket doesn't necessarily mean supported)

Answer (score 1):

The (UEFI-)[BIOS](https://wiki.osdev.org/BIOS) recognizes and initializes the components (as RAM) in a computer. After the components are initialized, an *Operating System* takes care of managing them. UEFI-BIOS and legacy BIOS are both closed-source. So if you really want to dig deep into the specifics of this, have a look at [CoreBoot](https://www.coreboot.org/) which is an Open Source implementation of that low-level functionality.

There are programs running on these *Operating Systems* that can present the information available (by reading out the [ACPI table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) and/or the older [MPS table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiProcessor_Specification)):

1. For Windows, there are the following programs amongst others

   - [CPU-Z](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html)
   - [HWInfo](https://www.hwinfo.com/)
   - and others, some of them listed [here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/easily-extract-your-computers-hardware-information/)
2. For Linux, there are standard commands like

   - `lspci` for all PCI devices
   - `lsusb` for all USB devices
   - `lshw` for all hardware
   - `smartctl` for all SATA/IDE devices